# Load Js file in single view Ionic Framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new in Ionic Framework, so I don't know if my question looks so obivous. I need run a custom JS in a single view. I only insert JS files in Index.html page. But this page is consumed for all views in projects, so I think is not necesary load my custom JS file in all views if it will be used in single one.

How can I figure this out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post your code in codepen or jsfiddle to have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to put your custom code in the controller for that view.